# Pandas - Skip number of rows given in a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

Consider a `pandas` dataframe, the task is to skip number of rows which are given in a `NumPy` array.

For instance, take this example:

```
# NumPy array    
arr = np.array([2, 5, 1, 3])
arr
array([2, 5, 1, 3])

# Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [18, 2, 32, 8, 9, 6645, 2, 4, 5, 688, 99, 5, 2, 223, 33, 85],
                    'val':['f','a','r', 's', 't', 'x', 'l', 'y', 'yy', 'gg', 's', 'ss', 'tt', 'qq', 'p', 'aa']})

df

   num  val
0   18  f
1   2   a
2   32  r
3   8   s
4   9   t
5   6645    x
6   2   l
7   4   y
8   5   yy
9   688 gg
10  99  s
11  5   ss
12  2   tt
13  223 qq
14  33  p
15  85  aa
```

Expected output:

```
   num  val
2   32  r
8   5   yy
10  99  s
14  33  p
15  85  aa
```

Comment: Can you please explain your output?

Comment: The output are rows after other rows are skipped by the numbers given in array. So `arr` first element is `2` so from dataframe `df`, `2` rows have been skipped and then third is taken, now process chooses next element which is `5` and skips next 5 rows, and so on.

Comment: Whats the logic of last row 85 aa

Comment: @Suresh take the row after the last "skipper" in `arr`.

Comment: Do you need only next row after last `arr` ? Or another rows is necessary skip ?

Comment: get next row after skips and rest all rows if values in `arr` ends. As happened to row index `15`

Comment: @meW jpp and I updated our answers to fit this requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of dropping rows you wish to skip, consider the rows you wish to *keep*. You can do this with NumPy, utilizing [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to combine slices with scalars:

```
idx = arr.cumsum() + np.arange(len(arr))

res = df.iloc[np.r_[idx, idx[-1]+1]]

print(res)

    num val
2    32   r
8     5  yy
10   99   s
14   33   p
15   85  aa
```

Note we use `iloc` positional indexing only because your input dataframe has a regular `pd.RangeIndex`. To use index *labels* use `loc` instead.

If you need *all* rows after the last specified index, you can use:

```
np.r_[idx, idx[-1]+1: len(df.index)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating this answer because it has been clarified that *all* rows after the last "skipper" must be taken.

```
>>> rows = np.array([2, 5, 1, 3])
>>> rows = rows.cumsum() + np.arange(len(rows))
>>> 
>>> pd.concat([df.iloc[rows], df.iloc[rows[-1] + 1:]])
    num val
2    32   r
8     5  yy
10   99   s
14   33   p
15   85  aa
```